# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined when trying to receive an object scecific variable form a 2D array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am using a JavaScript library called "**P5.js**". It has a setup function, which is executed when everything has loaded, and a draw function, which starts too loop after setup() is executed.

I am trying to code a maze generation algorithm and I am using a multi-dimensional array (an array of arrays) for the grid called `x`, which only contains `Cell` objects.

I am creating the array like this:

```
//Global variable declaration
var x = [];

//What I write in setup()
for(var i = 0; i < nw; i++) {
  var y = [];
  x.push(y);
}

for(var i = 0; i < nw; i++) {
  for(var j = 0; j < nh; j++) {
    var c = new Cell(i, j);
    x[i].push(c);
  }
}
```

In the `draw()` loop I display the cells with a function that is also called `draw()` like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  for(var j = 0; j < nh; j++) {
    x[i][j].draw();
    x[i][j].checkNeighbours();
  }
}
```

The `draw()` function draws a line on each side of the cell.

Now comes my problem:

I have a function called `checkNeighbours()` which wants to access the multi-dimensional array from the Cell object like this:

```
this.checkNeighbours = function() {
  if(this.indexY == 0 || x[this.indexX][this.indexY - 1].visited) {
    this.neighbours[0] = false;
  }
}
```

Now my browser only draws the first two cells (`x[0][0]` and `x[0][1]`) before saying (in the console): **"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"**.

The issue is not the possible out of bounds exception (as called in java), because it also does say the same thing when I remove the `- 1`. When I input `x[0][0].visited` it return `false` and not `undefined`.
Does anyone have an idea what causes this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It's not saying "Cannot set property 0 of undefined" so, it can't be the this.neighbors[0] = false line.

x[this.indexX] must be undefined.

Try this:

```
this.checkNeighbours = function() {

  console.log('this.indexX: ', this.indexX);
  var xx = x[this.indexX];
  console.log('xx: ', xx);

  if(this.indexY == 0 || x[this.indexX][this.indexY - 1].visited) {
    this.neighbours[0] = false;
  }
}
```

Also, just console.log(x) itself after it has been set up, before the first call to checkNeighbours, and examine it in the console and see if it contains what you're expecting it to.

Another possibility is that the error is not in this code at all, but in the Cell constructor or something.

What code line does the error reference?

Comment: In the console it prints the array (x) as is should.
But it also prints:
    xx: false
The line it refences is the line where I try to call 
    x[this.indexX][this.indexY - 1].visited.

Comment: What does it say for this.indexX? if you say console.log(this) does the thing it prints look like a Cell object?

Comment: Can you post your javascript to github or jsfiddle so we can try it out ourselves?